# How to create multiple Label in Button widget of Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, widget

I would like to know how to create buttons widget in Tkinter with multiple labels as the following figure.
[Buttons with sub-label.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOZRw.jpg) 
As you can see, that in some buttons there is a sub-label, e.g., Button "X" has another small label of "A". I have tried to search for the solution, but found none.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your labels in a `Frame`, and have the `Button` be the parent of that frame. However, you'd need to be a little bit clever and overcome some issues, such as:

- inability to click the button properly (you can only click on edges, because the frame containing labels is in the middle), which means you'd have to do some event-handling (clicking on the frame and the labels inside needs to trigger the same event as if the button was clicked)
- unsynchronised colours when hovering over the button itself
- and a few other minor details, like properly configuring the button's `relief` when it's clicked (don't forget, you may be clicking the frame or the labels!), etc.

Here is an MCVE:

```
import sys
import string
import random

try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

CHARS = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

class CustomButton(tk.Button):
    """
    CustomButton class inherits from tk.Button, which means it
    behaves just like an ordinary tk.Button widget, but it also
    has some extended functionality.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.command = kwargs.get('command')
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(fill='none', expand=False, pady=(3, 0))
        self.upper_label = ttk.Label(self.frame, text=kwargs.get('upper_text'))
        self.upper_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.bottom_label = ttk.Label(self.frame, text=kwargs.get('bottom_text'))
        self.bottom_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.frame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.configure(width=kwargs.get('width'), height=kwargs.get('height'))
        self.pack_propagate(False)
        self.clicked = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.clicked.trace_add('write', self._button_cmd)
        self.bind('<Enter>', self._on_enter)
        self.bind('<Leave>', self._on_leave)
        self.frame.bind('<Enter>', self._on_enter)
        self.frame.bind('<Button-1>', self._on_click)
        self.upper_label.bind('<Button-1>', self._on_click)
        self.bottom_label.bind('<Button-1>', self._on_click)

    def _button_cmd(self, *_):
        """
        Callback helper method
        """
        if self.clicked.get() and self.command is not None:
            self.command()

    def _on_enter(self, _):
        """
        Callback helper method which is triggered
        when the cursor enters the widget's 'territory'
        """
        for widget in (self, self.frame, self.upper_label, self.bottom_label):
            widget.configure(background=self.cget('activebackground'))

    def _on_leave(self, _):
        """
        Callback helper method which is triggered
        when the cursor leaves the widget's 'territory'
        """
        for widget in (self, self.frame, self.upper_label, self.bottom_label):
            widget.configure(background=self.cget('highlightbackground'))

    def _on_click(self, _):
        """
        Callback helper method which is triggered
        when the the widget is clicked
        """
        self.clicked.set(True)
        self.configure(relief='sunken')
        self.after(100, lambda: [
            self.configure(relief='raised'), self.clicked.set(False)
        ])


class KeyboardMCVE(tk.Tk):
    """
    MCVE class for demonstration purposes
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Keyboard')
        self._widgets = []
        self._create_widgets()

    def _create_widgets(self):
        """
        Instantiating all the "keys" (buttons) on the fly while both
        configuring and laying them out properly at the same time.
        """
        for row in range(5):
            current_row = []
            for column in range(15):
                button = CustomButton(
                    self,
                    width=1, height=2,
                    upper_text=random.choice(CHARS),
                    bottom_text=random.choice(CHARS)
                )
                button.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='nswe')
                current_row.append(button)
            self._widgets.append(current_row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(KeyboardMCVE().mainloop())
```

[image: Example]

Alternatively, a simple workaround would be to use Unicode superscripts/subscripts.

Comment: Thank you very much. I never thought that I could have a frame as a child of a button. As you said, I have to be a bit careful in handling the events. Now, I got a new idea to create an image and put it on buttons.

Thanks a lot.