# Add label to Tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter, button, label

I'm trying to add a label to a Tkinter button. A Tkinter button has a 'text' attribute which is great. However I need another similar text field on the button, i.e 2 text fields per button. So I would like to add a label as a child to the button. The problem with this is that it creates unpredictable behaviour. Actuating the button or even just hovering the mouse over the label causes the label to vanish.

```
button_1 = tk.Button(canvas, text='Take',command='take',width='12')
button_1.pack()
label_1 = tk.Label(button_1, text='Stream 1',font=('calibre',8))
label_1.pack()
label_1.place(x=10, y=10)
```

I can avoid this unwanted behaviour by adding the label to the same parent as the button.

```
label_1 = tk.Label(canvas, text='Stream 1',font=('calibre',8))
```

But by doing this I loose the convenience of positioning the label with the button's geometry, e.g inset by 10 pixels from left and 10 pixels from top of button. I plan to make a convenience method for adding hundreds of such buttons, and do not wish to be attempting to calculate each label in the parents coordinates. And besides, as a sub-child of the button, it becomes part of the button hierarchy, i.e. will move with the button, will be hidden with the button etc.

Comment: Seems like there's already question about this, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762061/how-to-create-multiple-label-in-button-widget-of-tkinter), does any of that info help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create multiple Label in Button widget of Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46762061/how-to-create-multiple-label-in-button-widget-of-tkinter)

Comment: To both comments above, yes that question is adressing the same issue. But the answer scares me. I can add the label to the same parent as the button and position it relative to the button. i.e. 'label_1.place(in_ = btn, x=10, y=10)'. But if the label is clicked it will block the button receiving the click.

Comment: @Jace999 Even you set the parent of the label to the button, the label still blocks the click.  So the acceptable answer is what you said in the comment: set parent of the label to the same as the button and use `.place(in_=button_1, ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can display multiple lines of text on a `Button` by embedding newlines in the text.
Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('100x100')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

button_1 = tk.Button(canvas, text='Take\nStream 1',command='take',width='12')
button_1.pack()

#label_1 = tk.Label(button_1, text='Stream 1',font=('calibre',8))
#label_1.pack()
#label_1.place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of result]

You can use the `anchor` and `justify` options to change the positioning of the text on the `Label`:

```
button_1 = tk.Button(canvas, text='Take\nStream 1', command='take', width='12',
                     anchor='w', justify='left')
button_1.pack()
```

Result 2:

[image: screenshot of second result]

Comment: This has potential. But ideally I need to access the different text fields (lines) separately as their contexts will have different meanings, programatically. In this case it would mean parsing the text field. More overheads to manage. I also want to justify the text fields differently which is now tricky

Comment: You can use the `anchor=`, `justify=`, and `padx=` options to make the text appear many different ways. Regardless, you're adding on to your question making it something different.

Comment: I'm just politely commentating on others suggestions, seeing how they took the time to make a suggestion. Anyhow, I'm not sure 'anchor' or 'justify' would allow me to place my text appropriately, such as aligning text left on line 1, centered on line 2 etc.. What I need to do is add a label, and bind it to the same method of the underlying button. I just have managed to get it to work yet.

Comment: A `Label`'s `anchor` and `justify` options don't provide control that fine-grained over the text—they apply to all of it. Therefore you should consider using a [`Text`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm) widget instead because it does. Besides that, there's also [`Canvas` window objects](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_window.html), into which you could place a `Frame` containing multiple sub-widgets, thereby giving you *very* fine-grained control over them all.